# Sum of multiplicative functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Let $f_1, f_2$ multiplicative functions such that $f_1 \ne 0$ and $f_2 \ne 0$.

I want to show that $f_1 + f_2$ is multiplicative if and only if $f_1 = -f_2$

I tried starting the "only if" part as follows:

$$f_1(n) + f_2(n) = (f_1 + f_2)(n) = (f_1 + f_2)(p_1^{k_1}) \cdot ... \cdot (f_1 + f_2)(p_r^{k_r})$$

And then opening the binomial-like expression but I couldn't get it to be zero so that $f_1(n) = -f_2(n)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: doesn't a multiplicative function $f$ verify $f(1) = 1$ ?

Comment: if $f_1 = 0$ then $f_1 + f_2$ is multiplicative for any $f_2$, can you provide your definition of multiplicative?

Comment: @Amit the case "$f_1 = 0$ or $f_2 = 0$" is already discarded by OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y$ be coprime.
$$(f_1+f_2)(xy)=f_1(xy)+f_2(xy)\\=f_1(x)f_1(y)+f_2(x)f_2(y)=_{demand}(f_1+f_2)(x)\cdot(f_1+f_2)(y)\\=f_1(x)f_1(y)+f_2(x)f_2(y)+f_1(x)f_2(y)+f_1(y)f_2(x)$$
The demanded equality above will hold if and only if $f_1(x)f_2(y)=-f_1(y)f_2(x)$  for **all** such $x,y$. Can you finish the proof?

Comment: @insipidintegrator but notice that x,y are coprimes so it can't be that x=y

Comment: @TamirVered You don't need to take $x=y$ to conclude that $f_1=-f_2$.

Comment: $f_1(y)$ and $f_2(y)$ are multiplicative so they equal 1 for $y=1$ and thus from the last equality that is correct for all $y$ we get $f_1(x)=-f_2(x)$. Thanks!